# Loop the remaining elements within a loop

Tags: python, loops

I have the following text:

```
ERROR: <C:\Includes\Library1.inc:123> This is the Error
Call Trace:
    <C:\Includes\Library2.inc:456>
    <C:\Includes\Library2.inc:789>
    <C:\Code\Main.ext:12> 
    <Line:1> 
ERROR: <C:\Includes\Library2.inc:2282> Another Error
Call Trace:
    <C:\Code\Main.ext:34>
    <C:\Code\Main.ext:56>
    <C:\Code\Main.ext:78>
    <Line:1> 
ERROR: <C:\Code\Main.ext:90> Error Three
```

I would like to extract the following information:

```
line, Error = 12, This is the Error
line, Error = 34, Another Error
line, Error = 90, Error Three
```

Here is how far I got:

```
theText = 'ERROR: ...'
ERROR_RE = re.compile(r'^ERROR: <(?P<path>.*):(?P<line>[0-9]+)> (?P<error>.*)$')
mainName = '\Main.ext'
# Go through each line
for fullline in theText.splitlines():
    match = self.ERROR_RE.match(fullline)
    if match:
        path, line, error = match.group('path'), match.group('line'), match.group('error')
        if path.endswith(mainName):
            callSomething(line, error)
        # else check next line for 'Call Trace:'
        # check next lines for mainName and get the linenumber
        # callSomething(linenumber, error)
```

What is the pythonic way to loop the remaining elements within a loop?

Solution:
http://codepad.org/BcYmybin

Comment: Why is error 3 inconsistent with the rest of the errors?

Comment: Sorry, it is not clear. I want the errorText but the line number of the closest Main.ext file from the call trace. Error 3 is already from Main.ext

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
        # else check next line for 'Call Trace:'
        # check next lines for mainName and get the linenumber
        # callSomething(linenumber, error)
```

With this:

```
    match = stackframe_re.match(fullline)
    if match and error: # if error is defined from earlier when you matched ERROR_RE
        path, line = match.group('path'), match.group('line')
        if path.endsWith(mainName):
            callSomething(line, error)
            error = None # don't report this error again if you see main again
```

Note the indentation. Also initialize `error = None` before the loop begins and set `error = None` after the first call to `callSomething`. In general, the code I've suggested should work for properly-formatted data, but you might want to improve it so it doesn't give misleading results if the data does not match the format you expect.

You will have to write stackframe_re, but it should be an RE that matches, for example,

```
    <C:\Includes\Library2.inc:789>
```

I don't really understand what you mean when you say "loop the remaining elements within a loop". A loop continues to the remaining elements by default.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even think to do it in one pass. I was thinking of a nested loop after detecting the ERROR line.

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question, regarding how to loop over remaining lines, is: change the first line of the loop to

```
lines = theText.splitlines()
for (linenum, fullline) in enumerate(lines):
```

Then, after a match, you can get at the remaining lines by looking at `lines[j]` in an inner loop where `j` starts at `linenum+1` and runs until the next match.

However, a slicker way to solve the problem is to first split the text into blocks.  There are many ways to do this, however, being a former perl user, my impulse is to use regular expressions.

```
# Split into blocks that start with /^ERROR/ and run until either the next
# /^ERROR/ or until the end of the string.
#
# (?m)      - lets '^' and '$' match the beginning/end of each line
# (?s)      - lets '.' match newlines
# ^ERROR    - triggers the beginning of the match
# .*?       - grab characters in a non-greedy way, stopping when the following
#             expression matches
# (?=^ERROR|$(?!\n)) - match until the next /^ERROR/ or the end of string
# $(?!\n)   - match end of string.  Normally '$' suffices but since we turned
#             on multiline mode with '(?m)' we have to use '(?!\n)$ to prevent
#             this from matching end-of-line.
blocks = re.findall('(?ms)^ERROR.*?(?=^ERROR|$(?!\n))', theText)
```

Comment: I did it in a single loop in the end, but this is the direct answer of how to do it the way I asked. +1.